# How to extend a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing my own array class (like `std::vector`) whose main data is a pointer to the beginning of an array. After I allocate, say, 8 elements in memory, I want to make the size of the array bigger. Is there any way we could check whether the memory after the end of the array is available? If yes, how can I obtain it? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector` as-is? Even if you are writing your own class, you can (and should) use `std::vector` for the actual array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allocate more memory for dynamically allocated array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015546/allocate-more-memory-for-dynamically-allocated-array)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: This is just an assignment that my professor gives us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly obtain new memory that is contiguous to an already allocated block. Everything is opaque and managed by the operating system and your application RTL's memory manager framework.

I see 2 possible approaches:

- allocate a larger block using `new[]`, copy the existing data into it, and then delete the original block using `delete []`.
- use C memory allocation functions (`malloc` / `calloc`) for your internal buffer so that you can then use `realloc` to extend it. But this could get tricky because you don't have automatic management of construction/destruction of objects contained in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You have exactly two possibilities:

- Allocate with `new[]`, expand by copying elements to a new array allocated with `new[]`, and `delete[]` the old array. Finally, one more `delete[]` when you're done.
- Allocate with `std::malloc`, expand with `std::realloc`, call constructors/destructors yourself with placement-`new` and explicit destructor calls, and deallocate with `std::free`.

Comment: However, if you use `realloc` you can't use any data type with a non-trivial constructor or destructor. `realloc` only copies bytes.